# using SoundManager 2 js to play multiple files

Tags: javascript, audio, soundmanager2

I'm using SoundManager2.js as my framework for cross browser audio features. I'm trying to understand the documentation but I'm having some trouble stopping one audio file and playing another.

Can someone give me an example of loading multiple audio files and being able to "swap/ switch" between them using the framework?

Comment: Do you mean a player swapping files on the fly, or multiple players, with only one playing at a time?  You can look at http://openmix.co/browse.php for an example of the latter.

Comment: a player swapping files on the fly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can call `soundManager.stopAll()` or `soundManager.pauseAll()` ([documentation](http://keywestsauce.com/scripts/soundmanager/doc/)) before you start your desired sound. Believe the below code should work kind of just picked and chose from some code I've written before:

```
soundManager.setup({
    preferFlash: false,
    //, url: "swf/"
    onready: function () {
        soundManager.createSound({
            url: [
                "http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/audio/quick/test.mp3", "http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/audio/quick/test.ogg"
            ],
            id: "music"
        });
        soundManager.createSound({
            url: [
                "http://www.w3schools.com/html/horse.mp3", "http://www.w3schools.com/html/horse.ogg"
            ],
            id: "horse"
        });
        soundManager.play("music"); //start playing annoying music
    }
}).beginDelayedInit();
```

And to start horse and pause all other sounds currently playing in a click event:

```
$("#horse").click(function () {
    soundManager.stopAll();
    soundManager.play("horse");
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/uxESuGoF/2)**